# Capturing both special keys and key case within Javascript events

Tags: javascript, jquery, keycode

I've been doing a bit of work with Javascript key events (*keyup*, *keydown*, *keypress*) and have concluded that each has their advantages and disadvantages when trying to determine what key(s) the user has pressed.

By using [event.which](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/) as provided by jQuery it would seem that *onkeypress* will provide character codes that are case sensitive. i.e. 65-90 for A-Z and 97-122 for a-z. However, special keys such as the directional don't trigger onkeypress. They however will trigger a *keyup*/*keydown*, but those won’t provide case sensitive codes.

Does there exist a "best of both worlds" solution that will provide both case sensitive and special key detection that does not require manual simultaneous monitoring of several events?

Comment: Short answer, nope, you have to listen to at least two events to get both. The longer answer would be to listen for the shift / control events, and figure out the case based on that.

Comment: you can look for e.shiftKey on keydown/up events, which will hit capitals. The one issue is when using CAPS lock, the key would be upperCase and not have shiftKey.

Answer (score 1):

When listening for the keyup event

```
$(document).on('keyup', on_key_up);

function on_key_up(event)
{
    console.log('keycode:',event);      
}
```

i log this:

```
altKey: false
bubbles: true
cancelable: true
char: undefined
charCode: 0
ctrlKey: false
currentTarget: document
data: undefined
delegateTarget: document
eventPhase: 3
handleObj: Object
isDefaultPrevented: function ot(){return!1}
jQuery19106670567644760013: true
key: undefined
keyCode: 69
metaKey: false
originalEvent: KeyboardEvent
relatedTarget: undefined
shiftKey: false
target: body
timeStamp: 1367933052234
type: "keyup"
view: Window
which: 69
```

You want the keyCode (69 in this case), shifKey, altKey, ctrlKey.
example: If you press shift+arrow right, you will get keyCode:3, shiftKey:true.

```
function on_key_up(event)
{
if(event.shiftKey) // action

}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, but no distinction is made between the cases of letters. In your example I can't tell the difference between an 'e' (code 69) and an 'E' (again code 69) that was entered because of caps lock, nor an 'e' due to caps lock + shift.

Answer (score 0):

You may try [THREEx.KeyboardState.js](http://learningthreejs.com/data/THREEx/docs/THREEx.KeyboardState.html). Though this lib is used for JS games it can be useful in your case.